# Why parent project classes is not accessable in modules

Tags: gradle

I am trying to access some files of parent project into sub modules, but i am unable to access that.

My project structure looks like

```
project
  |---build.gradle
  src
   |---main
        |--java
            |---EnvConfig.java
  API_MODULE
    src
     |----main
            |---java
```

main build.gradle looks like

```
dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    compile project(":API_Module")
}
```

I want to access **EnvConfig** class in **API_Module** which is in parent, how i will do this. I am already compile **API_Module** in parent build.gradle, should in compile parent in child. I think it's not a good practice. Please suggest me the good practice.

Thanks

Comment: Describe the usecase more. Do you need to access the java source file or compiled bytecode of that class? Why do you need it?

Comment: The usecase is i have env config class(there are some methods are in it) in parent project where i have done configuration related environments. so i want it should be accessable in all modules.

Comment: Then that should be in a separate module that is used by all other modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much experience in Gradle, but this is obviously more related to your design of packaging and dependency of modules.

For a typical Maven multi-module project (which should also be safe to apply in Gradle), what you are trying to achieve should look like:

```
project
  + project-core/     <- things share across modules
  | + src/main/java/
  |   + EnvConfig
  |
  + project-api/      <- Your original API module
  | + dependency: project-core
  |
  + project-mod2/     <- Some other module that need to use EnvConfig
  | + dependency: project-core
  |
  + project-main/     <- Your original top-level project, 
    |                    which build on top of project-api & project-mod2
    + dependency: project-core, project-api, project-mod2
```

Answer (score 0):

**This would not work as adding a dependency from `API_MODULE` to `parent` will create circular dependency.**

Are you sure your main `build.gradle` needs to have a compile dependency to `API_MODULE`?